# Given zeros find 2-variable polynomial that has these zeros

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a polynomial of smallest degree that has exactly these zeros (no more):
$(0,0),
(1,0),
(0,1),
(1,1)$.
In one dimension this is easy; you write

$$
 (x-x_0)(x-x_1)
$$

How do you do that in 2 variables?

Comment: $xy$ comes to mind.

Comment: How?  That has zeros all along both axes.

Comment: Ah, you're right, the word "exactly" escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the function must be tangent to the $x$-$y$ plane only at those four points, so perhaps a better one-dimensional analogy would be the fourth-degree function

$$
f(x) = x^2(x-1)^2
$$

where one multiplies the squares of the distances from $0$ and $1$.  Using that as a starting point, one might define the eighth-degree function

$$
f(x, y) = (x^2+y^2)[(x-1)^2+y^2][x^2+(y-1)^2][(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2]
$$

However, I haven't double-checked whether that works, or, if it does, whether it's minimal in degree.

ETA: Seems like it works, since it must be positive when the distances from each of the four points is positive.  Still don't know if it's minimal, though.  Hope this helps as a starting point.